# How can get how many <div> there are in a <div> father with selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have this code example:

[image: code example]

How can get how many `<div>` there are in a `<div>` father with selenium?

I have this code:

```
List<String> productName = new ArrayList<String>();

List<WebElement> divElement = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.list-group-item llamada-ajax-TA.text-center"));       

    for(WebElement w : divElement) {

        productName.add(w.getText());            
    }

    System.out.print(productName);
```

But only print the content save in the array and I need know how many `<div>` child element there are.

Comment: Simply `productName.size()` ?

Comment: The result with productName.size() is 1 and there are 8 <div> chield

Comment: What's the size of `divElement` then?

Comment: Rather, is `divElement` supposed to be getting all the children?

Comment: yes, but it does not

Comment: I think the selector is off. Try `"div.list-group-item.llamada-ajax-TA.text-center"` (note the extra dot in place of the space)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of unreadable css selector, you could use xpath selector:

```
// means: find div that has class 'list-group' and get all it's direct div children
List<WebElement> children = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='list-group']/div"))
System.out.println("Size: " + children.size()); // Size: 8
```

Comment: How is `div.list-group > div` unreadable? It's easier to read than the XPath and does the same thing.

Comment: @JeffC For someone who doesn't know either of them, I think xpath would explain itself as it points explicitly what should equal given values. For example, I could theoretically not know what dot `.` means in css selector. In the end, if someone knows both, in most cases there is no real difference, yet: xpath was designed to be used with any xml, not just html, thus it has more xml-ish features - like traversing from child to parent, and more. Css selectors were designed to target web elements for styling, so it may be faster on some browsers, but it's not really a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> childrenList = getDriver().findElement(By.className("list-group")).findElements(By.cssSelector("div.list-group-item.llamada-ajax-TA.text-center"));
System.out.println("Size: " + childrenList.size());
```

This will find the children under parent defined by class locator "list-group"